# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'removeChild': object is null or undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working on an asp.net mvc 3 application. The title tells what problem I have. I will describe how I get this error.

I'm using JavaScript to upload image from my razor view. The script is not that long so I'll post it here :

```
function fileUpload(form, action_url, div_id) {
        // Create the iframe...
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");

        // Add to document...
        form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
        window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";

        iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");

        // Add event...
        var eventHandler = function () {

            if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
            else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);

            // Message from server...
            if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
                content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
            } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
                content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
            } else if (iframeId.document) {
                content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
            }

            document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = content;

            // Del the iframe...
            setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 250);
        }

        if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
        if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

        // Set properties of form...
        form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
        form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
        form.setAttribute("method", "post");
        form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");

        // Submit the form...
        form.submit();

        document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "Uploading...";
        form.setAttribute("action", '/forms/displayform');
    }
```

By using this script I get the image in my controller where I do my business logic so I'm not sure if it's really the script that is causing this, but I can't find another reason while debugging. So when the controller finish its work I get a new tab open in the visual studio 2010 titled `Script block[dynamic]` and the following code is there :

```
function anonymous()
{
iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)
}
```

which is actually part of my JavaScript :

```
    // Del the iframe...
    setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 250);
```

I have very basic knowledge about JS. I use this code but I don't understand some parts of it. Here - by the comment and the code itself is somewhat obvious what's going on but if I comment this and try to upload an image I don't get error and this is something very tempting to do, but I think that most probably the code is OK and the reason to get this error is somewhere else, so I post here to get any help on what may cause this error and how can it be fixed?

P.S

And this is the form that I use for uploading the image:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Forms", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input name=@Model[0].DocumentId type="hidden" />

    <input type="file" name="datafile" id="file" onchange="readURL(this);" />
    <input type="button" name="Button" value="Upload Image" id="UploadButton" onclick="fileUpload(this.form,'/forms/upload','uploadImg'); return false;"/>
    <div id="uploadImg" style="display: inline-block;">
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" style="display:none;"/>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax for setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function(),milliseconds);
```

So , you should do something like this

```
setTimeout(function(){
           iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId);
           }, 250);
```

Comment: Well, I get the exact same error like the previous code but at least now I can make some sort of debugging in VS2010 and it shows that `parentNode` is actually Null. I'm not pretty sure what does this mean in the context of the whole function but I'm thinking would it be ok just to perform some sort of check like `if (iframeId != null) { //here the rest of the code; }` or there must be parent node and something is going wrong somewhere if it's null?

Comment: Where your iframeId lies...?? Do it has a parent ...??

Comment: Well, I think that the parent is set here - `form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);`. And to see what the form looks like check my edited question because I can't post it here.

Comment: `form.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId);` Use the same to remove too

Comment: I get `Microsoft JScript runtime error: DOM Exception: NOT_FOUND_ERR (8)` but this seems logical. The form is the parent. I need to remove node from the form. Which I guess is childNode for the form.

Comment: You are appending it in `form.parentNode` so removing also can be done from the same `form.parentNode`